# Cannot find merchant name & OAuthClient ID

Tags: android-pay

I'm new in using Google Wallet. I have created Google Wallet account because I want to integrate it to my website. I'm registered as a merchant and I have already downloaded PHP quick sample.

In that sample I need to change `config.php`. Information which are needed:

```
 - Merchant ID
 - Merchant Name
 - Client ID
 - OAuthClient ID
```

I was unable to find `merchant name` and `OAuthClient ID`. I know how this is probably stupid question but trust me I spent more than three hours searching for those information.

It seems how registration and configuring PHP Quick Sample is more difficult than the whole process of integration.

Every kind of help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting merchant ID and Name first you have to register with google for business here is the link [to register](http://getinstantbuy.withgoogle.com/) after that google will provide you the first two log-in credential, that is ' - Merchant ID
 - Merchant Name'

Second two credentials 
' - Client ID
 - OAuthClient ID'
can be generated from google cloud console  [here is the link](https://cloud.google.com/console)

Comment: Are you really sure how that is a correct answer and how that is what I need? My Employee's told me how he is already created Merchant Account. Is there any difference between Merchant account and Instant Buy account ? I was unable to create account and try to find those information because wallet isn't allowed in my country.. 

Thanks

Comment: Ya i think so because currently i am doing research on wallet.